# org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport not found spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have updated the spring boot version.

```
   springBootVersion = "2.1.13.RELEASE"   to "2.3.11.RELEASE"
```

Post that I am getting ResourceSupport not found error. I have reading hateoas documentation and understood that this particular class was renamed to something else. I have tried upgrading below dependencies but it did not help.

```
  compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0"
  compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0"
  compile 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
```

Can you help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found at Spring Hateoas doc (see at https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)
you should change, ResourceSupport is now RepresentationModel

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30514525)

Comment: The essential part is refered to "ResourceSupport is now RepresentationModel" as much it is like this in the documentation.